# What is the most efficient way to find a record whose value X does not happen in column Y?

Tags: sql, performance, linked-list

I have a SQL table with rows, and each row has (among other things) two columns that are related. Basically, think of the structure like this:

```
A | B    | Data
--|------|-----
1 | NULL | ...
2 | 1    | ...
3 | 2    | ...
```

As you can see, some of the values in column `A` exist in column `B`, but not all: For `A`=`3` there is no row that has `B`=`3`.

The structure has the specialty that each value in `A` and `B` only happens once, and basically the structure is as shown: Every record "points" to the ID of another record, so this is basically a linked list.

What I do now want is to find the row whose column `A` value has no matching value in any other `B` column.

In the given demo table, this query should return the record with `A`=`3`.

If there is only one row in the table at all, I want to have this single row as a result, although no reference exists.

If there is no row in the table, the query should return `NULL`.

I have already tried to use `SELECT … WHERE NOT IN`, but this does not work with `NULL` values as desired. I have also tried `SELECT … WHERE NOT EXISTS`: This does not have the `NULL` problem, but it's super slow for large tables.

So my question is: Is there an efficient way to find the row I am looking for, and if so, what does this query look like?

PS: I'm not asking for a specific database, so basically the SQL standard is fine. If there is a really well solution for a specific well-known database (such as MariaDB, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, …) I would also be interested in specific solutions for them, but generally speaking, I'm looking for a generic way to solve this issue.

Comment: The generic solution is based on NOT EXISTS, on which DBMS it was *super slow*? What indexes do exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
SELECT
    x.*
FROM
    tbl AS x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl AS y ON x.A = y.B
WHERE
    x.A IS NULL
```

The "efficiency" of this query depends on what indexes you have on the table rather than the query itself. Remember that SQL queries don't tell an RDBMS *how* to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN`:

```
select
    a
  from my_table
  where a not in (select b from my_table)
```

You can also use `MINUS` (Oracle):

```
select a from my_table
minus
select b from my_table
```

Comment: Thanks for the Oracle-specific solution, but the generic version with `NOT IN` was exactly what I had written what did not work because of the way `NOT IN` deals with `NULL` values 